# Countifs with specified row and column value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using the data below,

```
                       HR   SC  HR
Banks                  1    2   2
Insurance              1    5   2
Banks                  2    3   9
Diversified Finance   10    6   7
Banks                  2    4   3
Insurance              8    2   2
```

I am trying to find the number of times a certain digit shows up for the banks in HR. Have tried to use, `countifs` and `if(and(row="Banks",column="HR"),countif(A1:D8,"1"))` but these didn't work.

My goal is to have:

```
         HR
Banks 1  1
Banks 2  3
Banks 3  1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

A `SUMPRODUCT` formula will work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7="Banks")*($B$1:$D$1="HR")*($B$2:$D$7=1))
```

...or equivalent dynamic formula (as used below)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7=$A12)*($B$1:$D$1=C$11)*($B$2:$D$7=$B12))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! I had also tried sumproduct but never realized to remove the cell with no value!